# Inner Join com 3 tabelas e Joins diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saudações,

preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de dados que leva em consideração 3 tabelas. 
Utilizamos um aplicativo proprietário que não tem atualização automática, portanto, preciso monitorar quem não está com a ultima versão e atualizá-lo.

A consulta em si, eu já resolvi. Contudo, aqui tem cerca de 200 usuários e diversos gerentes. Para facilitar a minha vida e não ter que ir de usuário em usuário atualizando o aplicativo, preciso buscar quem é o gerente das pessoas e pedir aos gerentes que tragam o smatphone para que eu faça a atualização.

Nesse recorte, leva-se em consideração 3 tabelas: USUARIO, FUNCIONARIO e FUNCIONARIOSUBORDINADO.
Para buscar os usuários ativos que estão desatualizados eu fiz a seguinte consulta.

```
SELECT USUARIO.NOME,
USUARIO.ID,
USUARIO.TIPO,
USUARIO.AP,
USUARIO.VERSAO,
USUARIO.UNIQUEID,
(SUBSTRING(USUARIO.DTSINCRONIA,7,2)+ '/'+SUBSTRING(USUARIO.DTSINCRONIA,5,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(USUARIO.DTSINCRONIA,1,4)) AS DATA
FROM USUARIO INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIO ON (USUARIO.ID = FUNCIONARIO.USUARIO)
WHERE USUARIO.ATIVO = 'S'
AND USUARIO.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%224'
AND USUARIO.VERSAO <> ''
AND FUNCIONARIO.DTDEMISSAO = ''
AND FUNCIONARIO.DELETED <> '1'
ORDER BY USUARIO.VERSAO;
```

Para buscar quem é o Gerente desses FUNIONARIOS eu preciso consultar a tabela FUNCIONARIOSUBORDINADO.
Contudo, não tenho muita noção de como farei isso. Alguém pode me ajudar em como farei esta consulta?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem o problema, acredito que basta incluir a tabela na sua consulta:

```sql
SELECT u.NOME,
u.ID,
u.TIPO,
u.AP,
u.VERSAO,
u.UNIQUEID,
(SUBSTRING(u.DTSINCRONIA,7,2)+ '/'+SUBSTRING(u.DTSINCRONIA,5,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(u.DTSINCRONIA,1,4)) AS DATA,
fs.SUBORDINADO
FROM USUARIO u INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIO f ON (u.ID = f.USUARIO)
INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIOSUBORDINADO fs ON (f.CODIGO = fs.CODIGO)
WHERE u.ATIVO = 'S'
AND u.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%224'
AND u.VERSAO <> ''
AND f.DTDEMISSAO = ''
AND f.DELETED <> '1'
ORDER BY u.VERSAO;
```